# Method is not calling in iPhone but calling in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am very frustrated to know that a method is working fine in iOS simulator but not working in my iPhone. I am using iPhone 4S.

What I am trying to do is, I want to add "Edit" button while swiping instead of "Delete" button. I am using the following code for that-

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}

- (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewRowAction *edit = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault
                                                                title:@"Edit"
                                                              handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
                                                                  // Open Edit Screen
                                                                  isEdited = YES;
                                                                  if (isSearchResult) {
                                                                      editArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                                                                  }
                                                                  else{
                                                                      editArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[soArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                                                                  }

                                                                  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addCateChild" sender:nil];
                                                              }];
return @[edit];
}
```

When I run it in simulator then it works fine. See the screenshot:

[image: This is what working on simulator.]

And when I run it in iPhone, then it's showing "Delete" button instead of "Edit". See the screenshot-

[image]

I am not able to understand what can be the possible issue in the code. When I place a breakpoint in "editActionsForRowAtIndexPath" then it's not hit by iPhone but it's hit by simulator.

Please help me if someone knows the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the version of your device? as "editActionsForRowAtIndexPath" is Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

Comment: @Sujania Okay.. I haven't checked for it's availability in older versions. I have just checked the version of my device i.e. 7.1.2. Means it isn't available for this version.. Right?

Comment: Yes..please refer this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: @LancelotdelaMare I tried to use that in my code. It was working in it's demo project only. It was crashing when I was trying to use that library while setting delegate to cell...

Comment: @Sujania Ok got it. Thank you for the help. Actually I was new in the iOS development. It will take little more time for me to Understand.. :)

Comment: @LancelotdelaMare Will it work in older versions of iOS as well?

Answer (score 2):

For all iOS from 5 to 8, use [MGSwipeTableCell](http://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell)

> Tested on all iOS versions on iPhone and iPad: iOS 5, iOS 6, iOS 7 and iOS 8.

While `MGSwipeTableCell` is not a direct response to `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` only being available in iOS 8+, it is a reasonable alternative. It also allows for multiple buttons, and multiple swipe directions.